# Solidity issue "TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "address""

Tags: byte, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

[problem is in the last line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWOZE.png)

```
function bytesToAddress(bytes memory b) public view returns (address) {
    uint256 result = 0;
    for (uint256 i = b.length - 1; i + 1 > 0; i--) {
        uint256 c = uint256(uint8(b[i]));

        uint256 to_inc = c * (16**((b.length - i - 1) * 2));
        result += to_inc;
    }
    return address(result);
```

Can't figure out how to make this function work properly. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function bytesToAddress(bytes memory b) public view returns (address) {
  uint result = 0;
  for (uint i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      uint c = uint(b[i]);
      if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
          result = result * 16 + (c - 48);
      }
      if(c >= 65 && c<= 90) {
          result = result * 16 + (c - 55);
      }
      if(c >= 97 && c<= 122) {
          result = result * 16 + (c - 87);
      }
  }
  return address(result);
}
```

bytes32 values are in hexadecimal format. Here is the table show how ranges in if statement is calculated

[image]